# PyYAML - how to deal with composition

Tags: python, yaml, composition

I've been trying to use YAML as I love the readability of it.

However, I'm a bit stumped at the best way to put in components/deal with composition.

Let's say I have this as a class I'm trying to replicate:

```
basicai = aggressiveAI()

fightercomponent = fighter(strength=10, dexterity=5, death=dramaticdeath())

orc = Object(name='orc', hp=100, fighter=fightercomponent, ai=basicai)
```

How would be the best way to do something like this in YAML?

Mostly, I'd like to be able to not end up with a long list of specifically named component objects and main objects all spread out.

Comment: So you're creating an `orc` and assign the value of a variable we don't know to `fighter`, and afterwards, you change the value of that variable… what do you want to show with that? Your code is confusing.

Comment: Also, your YAML code is invalid and does not help in demonstrating what you want to do. `aggressiveAI()` seems to be a call, what does that do in the YAML data? `=` is not a special character in YAML, you probably want to have `:`.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited it a bit for clarity - the YAML data was just some pseudo-code for the type of thing I was trying to achieve. Although = seems to work fine for me in YAML code.

Comment: So what's the value of `fightercomponent` and `basicai` in line 1 of your code? And why are you changing that value afterwards? Also, what's the definition of `aggressiveAI()` and `dramaticdeath()`?

Comment: Ahh, silly mistake, I was setting them after instead of before. AggressiveAI() is just a class that sets what the monster should do and a few other class bits, and dramaticdeath() is just a function that posts a few messages to the player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have proper constructors and representers to create the objects, you can do:

```
- !AggresiveAI &basicai 
- !Fighter &fightercomponent
     strength: 10
     dexterity: 5 
     death: dramaticdeath
- !Object 
    name: orc
    hp: 100
    fighter: *fightercomponent
    ai: *basicai
```

The only thing problematic is your function call to `dramaticdeath` as YAML stores objects and not function calls. So make that a lookup from the string to the function in the `__init__` method of class `Fighter`

The toplevel doesn't have to be a list, you can e.g. make the toplevel a mapping. Just make sure your anchors are defined before using them in aliases.

Comment: Thanks for your help Anthon,
What I've tried to do is add all these items to a dictionary so that I can call them out: 
`monsters = {Object.name : Object for Object in yaml.load_all(monsterdata)}`

However I seem to be getting a 'AttributeError: 'Fighter' object has no attribute 'name'' - I'm imagining this is because it's trying to read in every object separately. What would be the best way around this?

Comment: @Retro That depends on how you did define the class `Object`. I suggest you create a new question with the program as you have it now (and refer to this one in a link), because I don't think that can easily resolved in comments to this answer. And you shouldn't change your original question that much (and make it a moving target).

Comment: Thanks - I'll do just that. I'll mark this one as solved as I believe you've answered what I asked in the question from what I can print.