# PyYAML and composition, attribute error

Tags: python, composition, pyyaml

I've been trying to get to grips with PyYAML as I love it's readability, and would like to use it in a few open source projects I'm working as an alternative to JSON.

However, I'm struggling to understand exactly how to construct objects with composition. I opened this question: [PyYAML - how to deal with compositon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227826/pyyaml-how-to-deal-with-composition) and it seemed to work in terms of reading out the info, but not in the context of the full program.

Here's a stripped down example of what I'm trying to YAMLify:

```
import yaml
import data

class DungeonObject(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = u'!DungeonObject'
    def __init__(self, x, y, char, name, blocks=False, fighter=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.char = char
        self.name = name
        self.blocks = blocks

        self.fighter = fighter
        if self.fighter:
            self.fighter.owner = self


    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(x=%r, y=%r, char=%r, name=%r, blocks=%r fighter=%r)" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.x, self.y, self.char, self.name, self.blocks, self.fighter)

class Fighter(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = u'!Fighter'
    #combat-related properties and methods (monster, player, NPC).
    def __init__(self, hp, defense, strength):
        self.hp = hp
        self.base_defense = defense
        self.base_strength = strength
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(hp=%r, defense=%r, strength=%r)" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.hp, self.defense, self.strength)


monsters = {DungeonObject.name : DungeonObject for DungeonObject in yaml.load_all(data.monsterdata)}
print (monsters)
```

And my YAML file:

```
monsterdata = """
---
!Fighter &fighter_component
    hp: 20
    defense: 0
    strength: 4
!DungeonObject
    x: x
    y: y
    char: 'o'
    name: 'orc'
    blocks: True
    fighter: fighter_component
---
!Fighter &fighter_component
    hp: 9
    defense: 0
    strength: 10
!DungeonObject
    x: x
    y: y
    char: 't'
    name: 'troll'
    blocks: True
    fighter: fighter_component
"""
```

With this, I'm getting the error:
*line 32, in 
    monsters = {DungeonObject.name : DungeonObject for DungeonObject in yaml.load_all(data.monsterdata)}
AttributeError: 'Fighter' object has no attribute 'name'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each document should contain a sequence/list that consists of a `Fighter` and a `DungeonObject`. The former has no name, so you should filter on DungeonObjects that are actuall of type DungeonObject and not of type Fighter.

What is a bit confusing is that you use a variable DungeonObject as well, so try to use `dungeon_object` for the variable:

```
from ruamel import yaml

monsterdata = """
---
- !Fighter &fighter_component
    hp: 20
    defense: 0
    strength: 4
- !DungeonObject
    x: x
    y: y
    char: 'o'
    name: 'orc'
    blocks: True
    fighter: fighter_component
---
- !Fighter &fighter_component
    hp: 9
    defense: 0
    strength: 10
- !DungeonObject
    x: x
    y: y
    char: 't'
    name: 'troll'
    blocks: True
    fighter: fighter_component
"""


class DungeonObject(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = u'!DungeonObject'

    def __init__(self, x, y, char, name, blocks=False, fighter=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.char = char
        self.name = name
        self.blocks = blocks

        self.fighter = fighter
        if self.fighter:
            self.fighter.owner = self

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}(x={!r}, y={!r}, char={!r}, name={!r}, blocks={!r} fighter={!r})".format(
            self.__class__.__name__, self.x, self.y, self.char, self.name,
            self.blocks, self.fighter)


class Fighter(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = u'!Fighter'
    # combat-related properties and methods (monster, player, NPC).

    def __init__(self, hp, defense, strength):
        self.hp = hp
        self.base_defense = defense
        self.base_strength = strength

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}(hp={!r}, defense={!r}, strength={!r})".format(
            self.__class__.__name__, self.hp, self.defense, self.strength)

monsters = {}
for doc in yaml.load_all(monsterdata, Loader=yaml.Loader):
    for dungeon_object in doc:
        if isinstance(dungeon_object, DungeonObject):
            monsters[dungeon_object.name] = dungeon_object

print (monsters)
```

Which gives:

```
{'orc': DungeonObject(x='x', y='y', char='o', name='orc', blocks=True fighter='fighter_component'), 'troll': DungeonObject(x='x', y='y', char='t', name='troll', blocks=True fighter='fighter_component')}
```

I updated the `__repr__` to use the more modern `.format()` method. Since I am using ruamel.yaml (which is a superset of PyYAML functionality and backwards compatible), I need to specify the Loader explicitly to suppress the warning that `load_all` is unsafe when using the default loader. (Disclaimer: I am the developer of that package)

Comment: @Retro the quotes around the string come from using `{!r}` instead of `{}`. The former inserts  the result from the `__repr__` (which for a string is the quoted string), the later the result from `__str__` (ie. for string the characters without extra quotes).

Comment: Brilliant, that helps a lot - it all works now. Final problem I think is that the fighter class has some methods that revolve around the use of 'owner', like:         `bonus = sum(equipment.strength_bonus for equipment in get_all_equipped(self.owner))
        return self.base_strength + bonus`
These now throw a 'Fighter' object has no attribute 'owner' error.
I've defined in my Fighter class `if self.fighter: self.fighter.owner`, and it worked fine before, but it doesn't seem to work any longer. Any ideas?

Comment: If `self` has no owner, but is a fighter class then you probably should not be using `self.owner` as parameter to `get_all_equipped`, but use `self.fighter.owner`. But that is just a guess, without seeing the actual code. Make sure your code is under revision control and committed regularily then you can compare with what worked and/or roll back.

Comment: Fantastic, I just made an owner attribute and it seemed to work fine. Thank you so much Anthon, you've not only helped me sort this out but also become a better coder through learning how to look at these things.
Best of luck with ruamel!